# I Can't rotate a graph (-90°) matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i plotted 2 graphs and i want to rotate the right one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eWCa.png)90° degrees.
when i rotate it, the graph disappears, I don't know why ?
Could you Help me please

this is my result:

[**Befor Rotation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eWCa.png)

and this is what i got after rotating it

[**After Rotation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh5ek.png)

***THIS IS MY CODE***

````
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog 
import askopenfile from
matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg 
import FigureCanvasTkAgg import
pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
from matplotlib import pyplot, transforms 
import numpy as np              
import tkinter as tk 
import csv 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk```
   
root = Tk()
root.title("IHM")
root.geometry("750x450")
root.configure(background="#f5f5f5") 
label = Label(root, text="")
label.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=3)
   
   
Instructions = Label(root, text="Choose Your CSV File ...")
Instructions.grid(row=0, column=0)
   
   def Browseafile():
       file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
       file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
       print(file.shape)
       tab = np.array(file)
       time = tab[:, 0]
       print(time.shape)
       Amplitude = tab[::1, 1::3]
   
       print(Amplitude.shape)
       fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=150)
       fig.add_subplot(211).plot(time, Amplitude)
       chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
       chart.get_tk_widget().grid()
   
  
       base = pyplot.gca().transData
       rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-90)
   
       fig.add_subplot(122).plot(time, Amplitude, transform=rot + base)
       fig.add_subplot(121).imshow(Amplitude, aspect='auto', cmap='gray')
   
browse_btn = Button(root, text="Browse", bg="#6699cc", fg="#282C35", command=Browseafile) 

browse_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
   
 ```  root . mainloop()```
````

Comment: Is there a reason to not just `plot(Amplitude, time)`? Transformations are always a pain

Comment: yes, if you see the 2 pictures you will notice that i want to make it easier for the user to compare the 2 graphs